# How is dynasm supposed to be setup?

Tags: c++, compilation, jit, luajit

I'm trying to use [dynasm](https://luajit.org/dynasm.html). I've found several tutorials online for it, but they all require using weird lines of code such as `|.arch x64` that my compiler (MSVC) rejects. There are mentions of an offline Lua parser and `.dasc` files but none of these tutorials mention how any of this should be setup.

How is dynasm supposed to be setup in a project?

Answer (score 1):

DynASM allows you to write down assembly much easier by mixing C code and ASM code. DynASM files must be preprocessed. The output of compiling a DynASM file (.dasc) is a C file (.c) which you can later integrate in your project.

To preprocess a DynASM file you should use the dynasm program which comes with LuaJIT source code (`dynasm/dynasm.lua)`. The "weird" lines you mentioned are the ASM code that it's processed by DynASM. The asm code is stored as byte values into an array called `actions` in the resulting C program.

There's a great turorial on DynASM by Josh Haberman: [Hello, JIT World: The Joy of Simple JITs](http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/12/hello-jit-world-joy-of-simple-jits.html). The tutorial includes example code. The code is available as a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/haberman/jitdemo). Fetch it and start playing with it (note: currently master branch doesn't build, I just sent a pull-request to fix it).

Another good intros to DynASM are:

- [The Unofficial DynASM documentation](https://corsix.github.io/dynasm-doc/tutorial.html) (includes tutorials, instruction reference, etc).
- [DynASM Luapower](https://luapower.com/dynasm) (DynASM from .lua files).